# Powershell script to extract content from a text file and create Windows event

Tags: powershell

I want to pull content from a text file and raise an event.
The text file has 2 keywords: "Start" and End".
The data is between these 2 keywords.
The thing is, the 2 keywords appear mutiple times and I have to extract data multiple times from the text file and raise a Windows event in application log. I am new to Powershell. Any help is apprecaited.

Sample text file:

```
Start
aaaa
End

Start
bbbb
End

Start
cccc
End
```

Comment: What script/code do you have so far in your attempt to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple text file parsing is something I usually do with `switch`:

```
switch -case -regex -file foo.txt {
  '^Start$' { $data = @() }
  '^End$'   {
    # Write $data to event log. Get-EventLog or Get-WinEvent might help you here
  }
  '^(?!(Start|End)$)' { $data += ,$_ }
}
```